# Should I be proving this elementary fact about vector spaces without using a pre-established fact?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following elementary fact about vector spaces:

Let $c$ be a number $\not= 0$, and $v$ an element of $V$. Prove that if $cv = 0$, then $v = 0$.

Proof: Since $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ and $c \not= 0$, there exists $c^{-1} \in F$ such that $c^{-1}c = 1$. Hence $cv = 0$ implies that $$v = 1\cdot{v} = (c^{-1}\cdot{c})\cdot{v} = c^{-1}(c\cdot{v}) = c^{-1}\cdot0 = 0.$$

Here I'm assuming the fact that $v\cdot{}0 = 0$ for all $v$, which would have to be proved. However that exercise comes after this exercise, so I don't think my proof is how the author intended the proof to be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used $\cdot$ in two different senses as well as not distinguishing scalars and vectory: you have scalar multiplication in "$\mathbf{v}=1\cdot\mathbf{v}$" but dot product in "$\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{0} = 0$".

If you avoid it for scalar multiplication then you can say with $c \not =0$ and knowing $k\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$ and $1\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$: $$c\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0} \implies c^{-1}c\mathbf{v}=c^{-1}\mathbf{0} \implies 1\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$$ or in your style $$\mathbf{v}=1\mathbf{v}=(c^{-1}c)\mathbf{v}=c^{-1}(c\mathbf{v})=c^{-1}\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$$ just using properties of scalar multiplication.

Comment: I see now that I conflated scalar multiplication and the dot product.

Comment: @user2521987 So the next exercise, proving $v\cdot0=0$ for all $v$, is indeed about the dot product? We can't see the exercise for ourselves, and you haven't told us what text or exercise it is, so we need some verification.

Answer (score 2):

It's never a bad idea to prove your auxiliary results. Just note that the axioms imply $1\cdot\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$ so that

$$\mathbf{0}=c^{-1}\cdot \mathbf{0}=c^{-1}\cdot(c\cdot\mathbf{v})=(cc^{-1})\cdot\mathbf{v})=1\cdot\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$$